# summing common column values by using pattern matching of column names using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

example dataframe:

| lens | INV.NO | INV.NO | INV.NO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| Second | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| First | 3 | 7 | 2 |
| Second | 4 | 8 | 1 |

pattern matching (^INV.NO*) and pick up all 3 columns matching that and create new column plain_sum having the sum using pyspark.

| lens | INV.NO | INV.NO | INV.NO | plain_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 | 4 | 8 |
| Second | 2 | 5 | 3 | 10 |
| First | 3 | 7 | 2 | 12 |
| Second | 4 | 8 | 1 | 13 |

Answer (score 1):

I don't see 'prod' in your column names. You can use a simple list comprehension to get your 'plain' columns in a list, and use [`reduce`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/) with `add`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
col_list = [c for c in df.columns if 'plain-' in c]
df = df.withColumn("plain_sum" ,reduce(add, [col(x) for x in col_list]))

df.show(truncate=False)

+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|lens  |plain-dev 103|plain-pre 104|plain-rte 107|plain_sum|
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|First |1            |3            |4            |8        |
|Second|2            |5            |3            |10       |
|First |3            |7            |2            |12       |
|Second|4            |8            |1            |13       |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: i have modified my question can you try with that column name

Comment: you just need to change 'plain' in the list comprehension. so try it as ```col_list = [c for c in df.columns if 'INV.' in c]```. This means that it will sum all the columns that contain 'INV.', so all of them except 'lens'.

Comment: I used INV. instead of plain it is throwing an error saying cannot resolve '`INV.NO`' given input columns: [INV.NO, lens];;

Comment: are all your columns called the same?

Comment: i know to do in pandas df['plain_sum'] = df.filter(regex='^INV.NO$').sum(axis=1) but i want to achieve this using pyspark

Comment: Can you try and provide a clear representation of your actual dataframe in your question? There isn't a similar operation like ```sum(axis=1)``` in pyspark unfortunately.  You can do ```df.show(truncate=False)``` and post that in your question. That way i'll be able to help more.

Comment: i am using the sample dataframe which is there in the question. sum(axis=1) works in pandas but not in pyspark. is there any other way to sum multiple columns apart from reduce menthod because reduce fails when there is no pattern matched result

Comment: you can always convert to pandas  and then convert back to pyspark. Would that be okay for you or do you have a huge dataset?

Comment: actually in my real dataset pandas is failing because of huge dataset. so im trying a workaround in pyspark

Comment: Can you show me the result of ```df.columns``` please?